# Django template render speed issue for large queryset

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I have completed a web application for work and was doing some various tests. One of the tests was for a "exaggerated" number of items on a given page and how long it would take to load (the page is basically a dashboard for a helpdesk system) . My results are quite bad with the test page taking some 20 to 25 seconds for 1200 items on a standard spec system and 3 - 10s on a very high spec system.

I dont ever expect the active calls to reach that number on the dashboard but am looking at a worst case scenario. I have also tried with pagination, but I am probably implementing it wrong as going to the next page seems to rerun the queries and takes the same time as displaying all 1200 items irrespective of whether I am displaying 1 item or 10.

As the project is quite large and contains sensitive information, I cant really provide the code here for reproducible results but I created another basic project that basically highlights what I am experiencing. It can be downloaded here:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19yvzHugC7hjcVJpiHeYiEjyX-SA2_wu3?usp=sharing

This code is not that bad as not many attributes are referenced in the template (short.html) for loop which only refences 5 elements as opposed to the main projects 30 or so.

*The view*

```
def shorts(req):
all_shorts = Shorter.objects.all()

return render(req, 'shortner/short.html', {'all_shorts': all_shorts})
```

*The model*

```
class Shorter(models.Model):
short_num = models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True)
short_suf = models.CharField(max_length=8)
short_ou = models.CharField(max_length=256)
short_url = models.CharField(max_length=128)
short_desc = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True, blank=True, default='blah, blah, blah')

def __str__(self):
    return self.short_ou + ' is shortened to ' + self.short_url
```

*The html template*

```
    {% for short in all_shorts %}
          <div class="accordion-item" style="border-width: thick; border-color: darkblue;">  
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading_{{ task.reference }}">
              <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse_{{ task.reference }}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse_{{ task.reference }}">

                  <span class="row">
                  <span class="col"><strong>Number: </strong>{{ short.short_num }}</span>
                  <span class="col"><strong>Suffix: </strong>{{ short.short_suf }}</span>
                  <span class="col"><strong>Original URL: </strong>{{ short.short_ou }}</span>
                  <span class="col"><strong>Shortened URL: </strong>{{ short.short_url }}</span>
                  <span class="w-100"></span>
                      <br>
                      <hr>
                  <span class="w-100"></span>

                  <span class="col"><strong>Description: </strong>{{ short.short_desc }}</span>
                  </span>

              </button>
            </h2>
          </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I am definitely suspecting this template forloop as 1 query is run in under 1ms according to the django debug toolbar yet the page takes in this example 5 seconds to fully render (using the standard/weak pc as most users have those).

[image]

**The main project is currently live via IIS and is extremely fast but then again there is not much data just yet. To avoid any possible issues and assuming I am correct about the issue been with the template forloop, is there anything that I can do to try an speed up the template render?**

Comment: How is the queryset created? Show the view (or the relevant parts of the view) here.

Comment: Hello @Carcigenicate. I addd the view from the linked project. Its quite a simple view but for the deployed project I had to use selct and prefetch related as things where even slower without it.

Comment: Can you share the `Shorter` model?

Comment: Hello @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike. I have the model